# Response.Redirect is not redirecting my page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a gridview that has a button in which the OnClick event calls the button's OnClick method.  There is some processing code and then the redirect code.  There is also an OnClientClick event that calls a javascript function.

After clicking the button, the page doesn't redirect.  It only refreshes.

Here is the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLinkedOptions" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="table table-striped" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    Visible="false"
    Gridlines="Horizontal"
    EnableViewState="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Linked Number">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnLinkedNbr" CssClass="linkBtn" runat="server"
                    ClientIDMode="Static" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("LinkedNbr") %>' 
                    OnClientClick="showName(this.value)" 
                    OnClick="btnLinkedNbr_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        //Other ItemTemplate columns

    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No Results found
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is the click method:

```
protected void btnLinkedNbr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LinkedNbr = Convert.ToString(txtLinkedNbr.Text);
    DataView dv = dalLinkSearch.GetInstance().SearchByLinkedNbr(LinkedNbr);
    if (DataUtil.HasValue(dv))
    {
        Int32 LinkID = DataUtil.GetInt32(dv[0]["LinkID"]);
        if (LinkID == -1)
        {
            string BlockMessage = GetLookupTableItem("SystemLock", "LockMessage", "Security");
            Tracking.CommonUtil.Utils.NotifyError(BlockMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            Base_DAL.RefreshWorkingEntity(LinkedNbr, "LI");
            Response.Redirect("~/West/LinkedTask.aspx", false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Tracking.CommonUtil.Utils.notifyInfo("Linked Number Not Found.");
    }
}
```

I have tried ResolveURL() and plugged that value into the redirect method parameter with no luck.

There is an UpdatePanel on the page, but the gridview is not in it.

When debugging the click method, there is an error:

> ClientDisconnectedToken    'this.Response.ClientDisconnectedToken' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'   System.Threading.CancellationToken {System.PlatformNotSupportedException}

I am not sure if that is causing the problem.  It would be strange if it is because this same code, except for using a gridview, works throughout the project.

My question is why does my page refresh instead of being redirected.

Comment: Could you set a break point at `Response.Redirect`, and ensure that it gets hit?

Comment: I'm able to hit the code.

Comment: Could  you set `true` and see it makes any different? `Response.Redirect("~/West/LinkedTask.aspx", true);`

Comment: When I set it to true, I get the exception:  ExceptionState = Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.